Removing a capacitor to ground from an xbox controller circuit, what are the downsides, how to know what size capacitor to replace it with?
UPDATE with solution at the bottom of this post.
I am trying to fix an Xbox controller (Model 1914) which once plugged in acts as if the right stick button is pressed. Key behavior is that when initially plugged in, the button behaves as expected, but after about a minute it goes into permanently pressed mode. I am thinking that the first minute is the time for the capacitor to charge and then become leaky.
This is the diagram:

3 questions I have:

From what I understand, this capacitor works as a filter. This is a DC circuit (powered by 2 AA batteries), so ~3v. How important is it to have a filter here?

What are potential side effects of removing this capacitor? Not in general, but in this particular case, a button on a controller. (I think its key that this is probably the least used button on the controller, not something that would be spammed).

This is a tiny 1mm in size capacitor, I do not have the tools (microscope) to do the soldering to replace it. But if I attempted to replace it. How can I find out what size (capacitance) capacitor it is? This product does not have schematics with this kind of information available, and I believe it to be busted so I cant measure it to get a replacement. What are my options here as far as replacement? What will happen if I oversize it? or undersize it? I have some 3uf, 6uf, and 10uF capacitors, wondering if I should attempt to swap one of them in.


UPDATE: I ended up desoldering the capacitor, after this the button would no longer have phantom permanent ON. So I knew I was on the right track. I measured the cap and it appeared to be somewhere around 100pF. I put in a 100pF replacement on and controller seems to be working well now. No more issues. Caps that came on the board are miniscule, maybe 0.2 of a mm, even if I had this size I dont have the tools to solder it on (no microscope). So I used a larger 1mm cap, but had to run the ground wire to a different spot. Here is the result.


This appears to be an unusual failure as chip caps are very reliable, however solder connections are not.  You are correct to assume a live insertion causes a 0V closed contact.  The delay of 1 minute seems more like a thermal drift effect of the threshold with the input floating near the threshold or perhaps a floating input with no pullup R.  To verify this a DMM is needed to measure the cap voltage with a 1Meg DMM at 3V.
I might assume the Xbox uses a chip with internal pullup between 50k and 100k and the right stick microswitch will have a bounce time of at least 1ms. So the cap serves to suppress contact bounce on microswitches on closure so that when the switch closes then bounces and opens, the cap which is discharged is slowly pulled up to Vdd (V+ supply of interface).  The 33 ohm resistor serves to limit contact current and dampen the fall time step voltage to a few microsec.
The unknown resistance could also be measured but let's go with voltage. This could be 3V (?) normally open and 0V closed.  I compute about 33 nF to 100nF minimum is needed.   33nF *50k = 1.55 ms
If too big a cap is installed then the release time will be much longer approx Rpullup*C=Tau [s]
If the pullup R is external to the chip a bad solder joint is possible. Inspect for parts on the same traces.
recommendation: If Cap voltage does not stay at 3V (open switch) replace with 0.1 uF.
Simulation


Thanks so much for a detailed reply, although some of it is over my head. Ill try replacing it with different valued caps to see if it starts working as intended. But first Ill remove it and verify that the button is no longer acting as pressed after 1 min (would verify theory of leaky cap).

I removed the one on the board to verify that the button is no longer acting as pressed after 1 min, and yeah after multiple minutes no fantom presses. So it was definitely this cap.

I have replaced the cap with 100pF cap,  it seems to be working really well. I uploaded picture to the original post. Thanks again for your help.

must be a good switch to not bounce as 100pF is pretty small
